# How to redirect to home page after logout in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a simple react app, I try to logout and redirect to the home page after that, so I don't know why it doesn't work as expected can someone help me please.

here's my code :

**PrivateRoute.jsx**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    return (
        <Route
        {...rest}
        render={
            routeProps =>
            !!currentUser ? (
                <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
            ) :(
                <Redirect to={"/"} />
            )
        }
        />
    );
};
```

**Navbar.jsx**

```
  const handleLogOut = () => { 
          
        fire
            .auth()
            .signOut();
        localStorage.clear();
        console.log("Logout successful");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext)

return (
 <div>
         {currentUser ? (
  <li ><NavLink to={"/"}  exact className="Nav_link" activeStyle={{ color: 'white'}} onClick={handleLogOut}>Logout </NavLink> </li>
                              ) : (
  <li ><NavLink to={"/login"} className="Nav_link" activeStyle={{ color: 'white'}}>Login </NavLink> </li>
         )}
</div>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to hold the boolean of the auth in state using `useState()` hook and then redirect with the `!isAuth && <Redirect to="/"/>`
From the react-router library

Comment: I add  const [isAuth, setAuth] = useState(true); and on nav I added !isAuth && <Redirect to="/"/> but still doesn't work

Comment: Well now you set it to true and you want to check if it's false (the user logged out). I just gave you an example go ahead and play with it

Comment: In handlelogout I set it as false, ok thank you